Mi compresor de imágenes no funciona
En mi codigo existe una variable quality que maneja la calidad de comprensión de la imagen. Esta obtiene su valor al acceder al value de un slider que almacena valores de entre 0 a 1, el problema radica en que si colocas un numero manualmente en la variable quality este funciona y mantiene la calidad segun el numero colocado, pero si pones para que obtenga el valor del slider y la use para controlar la calidad no funciona y no comprime la imagen como debe.
Ignoren algunos nombres de variables 


var sliderVal = document.getElementById("pochoclo");
        
        function capoeira() {
            var juan = sliderVal.value;
            document.getElementById("contar").innerText = (Math.floor(juan*100)) + "%";
        }
        
        pochoclo.addEventListener("input", capoeira);
        
        function seleccionarArchivo() {
    document.getElementById("inputImage").click();
    
        }
        function cargarImagen(event) {
    const archivo = event.target.files[0];
    const lector = new FileReader();
    
    lector.onload = function() {
        const originalImageElem = document.getElementById('originalImage');
        originalImageElem.src = lector.result;
    }
    
    lector.readAsDataURL(archivo);
}
        function compressAndDisplay() {
         document.getElementById("comprimir").removeAttribute("onclick");
         
            var comprimir = document.getElementById("comprimir");
            comprimir.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-redo-alt fa-spin"></i>`;
            
            setTimeout(function(){
                comprimir.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>`;
            }, 4000);
            setTimeout(function(){
                comprimir.innerHTML = `Comprimir`;
            }, 5000);
        
            setTimeout(function(){
                const input = document.getElementById('inputImage');
            const file = input.files[0];

            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    const img = new Image();
                    img.src = reader.result;
                    img.onload = function () {
                        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                        const maxWidth = 500; // Tamaño máximo deseado para la imagen
                        const maxHeight = 500;
                        let width = img.width;
                        let height = img.height;

                        if (width > height) {
                            if (width > maxWidth) {
                                height *= maxWidth / width;
                                width = maxWidth;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (height > maxHeight) {
                                width *= maxHeight / height;
                                height = maxHeight;
                            }
                        }

                        canvas.width = width;
                        canvas.height = height;

                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                        // Calidad de compresión (0-1)                    
                      // Aca esta el problema
                      //el slider tiene el id pochoclo
                        var quality = document.getElementById("pochoclo").value;
                        console.log(quality);

                        // Convertir el lienzo a base64
                        const compressedImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);

                        // Mostrar la imagen original
                        
                        // Mostrar la imagen comprimida
                        const compressedImageElem = document.getElementById('compressedImage');
                        compressedImageElem.src = compressedImage;
                        compressedImageElem.style.display = 'inline-block';

                        // Mostrar el botón de descarga
                        const downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
                        downloadButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    };
                };
            }
            }, 4000);
            document.getElementById("comprimir").setAttribute("onclick", "compressAndDisplay()");
        }

        // Función para descargar la imagen comprimida
        function downloadImage() {
            const compressedImage = document.getElementById('compressedImage').src;
            const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = compressedImage;
            downloadLink.download = 'compressed_image.jpg';
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        }
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.1" id="pochoclo">




hola recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Otra cosa, decir no funciona o no hace lo que espero o no comprime como debe... no nos ayuda a entender que es lo que sucede en tu entorno de desarrollo. por lo menos ya verificaste si en la consola de desarrollo de navegador sale algun error o warnign relacionado???
